# Use of EJB entity bean as Map key

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

Is it OK to use an EJB entity bean as a Map key? Something like this:

```
Map <EntityBean,String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

I assume that since each row in a table will be mapped to a single entity bean object there shouldn't be any problems, but are there any implications? I'm not planning on persisting the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, EntityBean is an EJB implementation interface, not a client programming interface.  You should never have references to an EntityBean, only EJBObject or EJBLocalObject.

Regardless, no, `HashMap<EJB(Local)Object, ...>` is not valid because hashCode and equals are undefined for EJB(Local)Object per the EJB 3.2 optional spec, section 3.9 (or similar language in earlier versions):

> Note that the Enterprise JavaBeans architecture does not specify
>   “object equality” (i.e. use of the == operator) for entity object
>   references. The result of comparing two object references using the
>   Java programming language Object.equals(Object obj) method is
>   unspecified. Performing the Object.hashCode() method on two object
>   references that represent the entity object is not guaranteed to
>   yield the same result. Therefore, a client should always use the
>   isIdentical method to determine if two entity object references
>   refer to the same entity object.

There is no way in general to hash an entity bean reference because there is no way to determine its underlying identity.  Depending on the limits of what you're doing in your application, you might be able to use either `EJBObject.getPrimaryKey()` or {entityInterface,primaryKey} tuple as your map key (for some meta-programming, you could use `EJBObject.getEJBMetaData().getRemoteInterfaceClass()`).

(You might be wondering why the EJB spec restricts this.  Entity beans started as local only, and for a remote RMI-IIOP stub at least, equals and hashCode would compare the stub identity rather than the underlying object.  That would cause problems for logically identical entity references obtained via different servers or for complex primary keys where the serialized form is different for logically identical entity references.  Perhaps in theory the EJB spec could have provided some kind of EJB(Local)Object.getIdentity() that would have implemented hashCode and equals, but even then there are complexities in determining if two entity beans have the same underlying "type" (implementation app/bean? backing table? or what?), but it's mostly a moot point since the entity bean programming model is dead; use JPA.  If you're stuck with entity beans and can make assumptions in your application, then you can avoid these complexities/problems and successfully hash entity bean references as I describe above.)

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to use EJB to represent database row? As fa as I know, for that purpose there are JPA entities  (classes annotated with [@Entity](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html)). EJB beans usually provide some services for those entities (like CRUD operations or something more complex, you can read about service facade pattern).